# Partition on hard drive failing to mount

Tags: mount, hard-drive, home-directory

So my computer runs Ubuntu 20.04 and has a SATA SSD as containing the root, / , directory and another HDD containing the /home partition. About a week ago, I started to have a problem with the HDD and /home partition not being mounted on boot. It says "Device in error" then "A start job is running for dev-disk-by-uuid\xxx". That UUID is the one for my /home partition. I am still able to login after it eventually boots and when I open gparted, it gives me an I/O error on the drive. After a couple of reboots and waiting a while, it would eventually find the disk, mount the partition and it would work just fine with no issues. I originally thought this to be a hardware problem and that the HDD disk was just failing, that's why Ubuntu couldn't find/mount the drive on boot. But after troubleshooting every hardware step and running multiple test on my drive, nothing worked and the drive passed every test. I now suspect something could be wrong with Ubuntu, maybe firmware or drivers?
The drive works just fine when I plug it into a Windows PC and mount it using the problem EXT2fsb to read EXT4 filesystem drives.
I noticed the problem usually occurs after my computer has been off for a period of time. Say when I go to sleep at night and wake up, it fails.

This could still be a hardware problem but I want to eliminate the possibility that something may be wrong in Ubuntu, that's why it can't read the drive.

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X7KQ4.jpg) is my fstab for my SSD (sda) and HDD (sdb)

Any suggestions or ideas are appreciated!
Thank you

Comment: I would say you have a hardware problem not an OS problem. That is just my experience.

Comment: I also suspect a hardware issue, even if it (still) seems to work in Windows. Nevertheless, have the file system checked thoroughly (fsck -f) to check whether the issue persists after that. It may be useful to include the line for the drive in /etc/fstab in your post.

Comment: Is it an old slow HDD and fast SSD? System may be booting fast enough that HDD is not yet up to speed. I keep /home inside my / (root) on SSD, but have all data on HDD. And then you can have slower HDD or add fstab setting for data partition to mount only when accessed. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1013677/storing-data-on-second-hdd-mounting & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1058756/installing-all-applications-on-a-ssd-disk-and-putting-all-files-on-hdd-disk

Comment: I will run "fsck -f /dev/sdb1", which is my /home partition. I will also post the fstab file when I get back from work today.

Comment: The SSD and HDD are both relatively new (about a year old). The HDD is 7200RPM and should be fast enough. What is the fstab setting I can use for only mounting the drive when accessed? Is it a difficult process to move my /home to my / (root) on my SSD without data loss?